# Running a java program from gitbash(on windows) is throwing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java

My application structure is:

```
C:/test/project/resources
C:/test/project/libs
C:/test/project/classes
```

classes folder has package structure like com/test/App.class

I am running below mentioned command from /C/test

```
java -cp project/resources:project/classes:project/libs/* com.test.App
```

I also tried running below mentioned command from inside /C/test/project/classes folder

```
java -cp .:../resources:../libs/* com.test.App
```

In both the cases it throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException com.test.App.

Looks like something is wrong with the way i provided classpath. Can anyone help to identify what is wrong here ?

Comment: windows (running the java program from gitbash), Java 11.

Comment: Works for me, but then again, you didn't provide a [mcve]. Java 11 is modular. Perhaps you need to also set the _module path_ ?